# Spectrum relationship between non-symmetric matrix's principle sub-matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I'm considering this: Given a non-symmetric $\{0,1\}$ matrix $A$, define $A_{(i)}$ to be the principal submatrix which deletes $i$th row and column. If we denote $\rho(A)$ as spectral radius of the matrix $A$, then is there a criteria that helps to easily compare $\rho(A_{(i)})$ and $\rho(A_{(j)})$?

Intuitively, the sub matrix that have been deleted the rows and columns with more non-zero entries has lower spectrum radius, but I can not prove this, could anyone help me with it?

Comment: Let $A$ be $2\times 2$ and nilpotent.  What kinds of problems does this create?

Comment: Thank you for comment, but I seems to can not understand what you mean, could you be more specifier?

Comment: @Duber Consider the specific matrix
$$
A = \pmatrix{1&1\\-1&-1}
$$

Comment: @BenGrossmann Thank you, I think for this matrix, it is clear that $\rho(A_{(1)})<\rho(A_{(2)})$, but the matrix $A$ should be a  $\{0,1\}$ matrix, and if the dimension increases, I think it is still quite hard to analyse. I think I may not totally get your idea, could you explain a little bit more?

Comment: This isn't true. Consider
$$
A=\pmatrix{1&0&0&0\\ 0&0&1&1\\ 0&0&0&1\\ 0&0&0&0}.
$$
Then $A_{(1)}$ has fewer nonzero elements of $A$ deleted than $A_{(4)}$ does, but $\rho(A_{(1)})=0<1=\rho(A_{(4)})$.